What may be causing closed port at VPS?
I'm testing connections to a VPS trying to debug an issue.
For some port (3000 in this example) it's not possible to connect to the VPS.
The ufw firewall is disabled:
# ufw status
Status: inactive

# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input

The idea is try to receive some file at the port 3000.
In the VPS,
nc -l -p 3000 > nc_.txt 

On a remote computer:
cat sss.txt | nc 55.55.55.55 

The file is not received.
A test shows the port is closed:
$ nmap -p 3000 55.55.55.55
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org )
Nmap scan report for privacy (55.55.55.55)
Host is up (0.21s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3000/tcp closed ppp

I can't find what that line:
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input

could be using.
What should I look for?

iptables-save will show you everything

Ports are not opened by firewalls, traffic to/from them is just permitted/denied. Processes allocate and manage ports. can you confirm that there is a listener on TCP\3000 after you run your nc command? netstat -ntlup . if the listener doesn't exist, or exists but the local address is 127.0.0.1, then you wont be able to connect to it, regardless of firewalls. good place to start.

@Bravo, spot on!  Albeit I disabled ufw, many rules were still efective, including old ones that should not be active.  Had to flush all rules and then ufw enable.  Thank you all for your comments.

If this issue was resolved, could you write up an answer and mark it as such to help others who may have the same problems?

After the suggestion made by Bravo, iptables-save showed some rules from past ufw configurations that were still enabled that were blocking outside requests for port 53.
To clear them up, I did the following.
First, set the default policies for each of the built-in chains to ACCEPT.
The main reason to do this is to ensure that you won’t be locked out from your server via SSH:
 iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
 iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Then flush the nat and mangle tables, flush all chains (-F), and delete all non-default chains (-X):
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

After setting and enabling ufw again, the issue was solved.

Congratulations, you learnt that ufw is pretty shitty =}
